# Periodic noise on peak-to-peak plot

Tags: noise, servo, encoder

I've encountered a strage behaviour and would like to ask for suggestions.

I have a servo motor that is doing a jog movement with a fixed 250rpm. The motor drives a shaft through an epicycloidal gearbox. The servo drive is powered by 230V 50Hz.

I've inserted an encoder (US Digital S5-5000-236-IE-D-B using a CA-FC10-SH-NC-6 cable) with a 100mm circumference encoder wheel to the exit of the gearbox.
I've captured the output of the encoder with a Saleae logic analyser, and wrote a small python program that calculates and plots the elapsed time between successive rising edges.
Checking these plots I've discovered a waveform, which has 0.02s period. This tells me that there is speed variation during the movement.
I've checked the servo drive's software and monitored the movement, and I've seen almost perfect 250rpm (±1 rpm) output, which after the gearbox means 1/20rpm variation.

I think it's more an "encoder" or "measurement" issue, and my goal is to see a relatively constant speed output from the encoder.

Every valuable comment is appreciated.

LD.

[image: rising-edge distances]
[image: rising-edge distances zoomed]

Answer (score 0):

This error can come from a few sources that I listed from most- to least-likely, according to your description:

1. 50Hz interference causing sinusoidal variation of the threshold used to measure encoder output timing. If you change the motor RPM and the period remains 0.02s, that's your problem.

   Possible fixes: The output shaft of the transmission should be grounded using a metal or carbon brush, and this grounding should go directly to the GND terminal on the logic analyzer. The cable from the encoder to the analyzer should be shielded, and the shield attached to the GND terminal on the analyzer.
2. Improper coupling of the encoder to the output shaft. The circumference wheel is a very likely source of error if there's any sort of rubber/plastic lining on it. You need to confirm the specification of the wheel as to the runout. The encoder shaft in these little encoders should also be treated as-if it could accept no radial loading whatsoever.
3. Geometry errors of the gearbox. Look in the gearbox specs to see the maximum output-vs-input speed variation due to manufacturing tolerances.
4. Runout/misalignment inside the encoder. Cure: get a better encoder. But I doubt that's the problem here.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the comment. I've doubled the RPM and still got 0.02 period, but after going to 800 and 1600RPM the period became 0.03 and 0.04. This does not make sense for me, so I'll do further measurements and verification.